# iCloud Drive - Is there a way to manually refresh iCloud Drive files?

Tags: macos, icloud, applescript, catalina

There's nothing wrong with how my iCloud drive files sync. It's just that sometimes it takes several minutes for them to sync. Is there a way to manually trigger a refresh?

Comment: See if  copy pasting a file in your second device triggers it ?

Comment: Usually, sign out and in would be the way to force

Comment: Try adding an empty (or any) file to your iCloud Drive on the device not syncing.